# GitHub public to private with fork

Tags: github, fork

I have a current public repo, I forked that repo and I’m able to sync the origin/upstream repo changes periodically on my forked version. If I now make that initial repo private can I still get updates from it on my fork?

Answer (score 0):

From [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/#changing-a-public-repository-to-a-private-repository):

> **If a public repository is made private, its public forks are split off into a new network**.
>   As with deleting a public repository, one of the existing public forks is chosen to be the new parent repository and all other repositories are forked off of this new parent. Subsequent pull requests go to this new parent.
>
> In other words, **a public repository's forks will remain public in their own separate repository network even after the parent repository is made private**.
>   This allows the fork owners to continue to work and collaborate without interruption. If public forks were not moved into a separate network in this way, the owners of those forks would need to get the appropriate access permissions to pull changes from and submit pull requests to the (now private) parent repository—even though they didn't need those permissions before.

So to your question: no.
But you still can push feature branches to your (now private) original repo, and make PR from those branches, directly from the private repo.